# msg 175, The isnull function requires 2 arguments(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

After looking at similar issues I'm no wiser. What I have is a value returning that has two sets of numbers then a name i.e. (xxxx;xxxx;name). I'm trying to just return the name. The original code I've written (below) works if a name value/name is present.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(FIELD_VALUE,75, len (FIELD_VALUE))
FROM 
    [RWADMIN].[RV_ACTIVITY_FIELDS] P
JOIN 
    [RWADMIN].[RW_ASSOCIATION] A ON P.activity_ID = A.activityA_id
```

However it breaks the report if the value is blank as it returns a "NULL",

So I've thought this would work, but I get the above error.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(SUBSTRING(FIELD_VALUE,75, len (FIELD_VALUE)))
FROM 
    [RWADMIN].[RV_ACTIVITY_FIELDS] P
JOIN 
    [RWADMIN].[RW_ASSOCIATION] A ON P.activity_ID = A.activityA_id
```

Help please.

Comment: "The isnull function requires 2 arguments". You are passing one argument. What do you want it to return if the value is null? Put that as the second argument.

Comment: If you want to return blank value for null then pass '' as second argument and if want to ignore those records having field_value is null then add condition in where clause .... where field_value is not null. Let me know if you need any thing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsNull` takes an expression and a value to replace the `null` values. It check the expression value, if it is `null` returns the value that we provided for nulls and if not just returns the expression value, so if you want to return a **blank** when it is null you should use it this way:

```
ISNULL(SUBSTRING(FIELD_VALUE,75, len (FIELD_VALUE)), '')
```

Comment: Taher is correct, as are the other comments above. You have to remember that ISNULL is a function NOT a comparison.   FYI there is also a function called COALESCE that works the same as ISNULL but will return the first value that is not null. EG  COALESCE(MyName,Companyname,'No Name')

Comment: Thanks Taher that is exactly what I needed to get this working.